# What to use for playing sound effects in silverlight for wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio, effect

I know I can reference XNA for the SoundEffect class and that's what I've been doing so far but I was wondering if there was a better way than what I've been doing.

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;

using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("test.mp3"))
{
          var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
          FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
          effect.Play();
}
```

For my test app I have 20 sounds each 1 second long that I want to play once button are pressed. I'm playing around with different techniques but if possible I'd like to know how professionals go about doing this before I commit in making a sound effect based app. Little things such as loading the sound effect first or loading it the instance the button is pressed would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I did do some reading on MediaElement and they don't suggest using it for short sounds but rather long tracks such as background music.

Comment: I think the soundeffect excepts a wav file stream not mp3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would use [PhoneyTools SoundEffectPlayer](http://phoney.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SoundEffectPlayer%20class&referringTitle=Home)

> This class is used to play SoundEffect
>   objects using the XNA integration. The
>   player must live long enough for the
>   sound effect to play so it is common
>   to have it scoped outside a method.
>   For example:

```
public partial class MediaPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
  // ...

  SoundEffectPlayer _player = null;

  private void playButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("alert.wav", UriKind.Relative));
    var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(resource.Stream);
    _player = new SoundEffectPlayer(effect);
    _player.Play();

  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using phoneytools to play 4 different sounds at the same time and it still lags I also tried the example from the post below and it does the same thing. I'm not sure why I'm getting this lag. Both on the emulator and phone.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good example would be the official sample on [AppHub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/silverlightsound). It demonstrates how to play multiple sounds. You can directly download the sample from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=207868).

> This sample demonstrates how to use
>   the XNA Framework's SoundEffect and
>   SoundEffectInstance classes to play
>   multiple sounds simultaneously in a
>   Silverlight application for Windows
>   Phone. It also shows a simple way to
>   set up a DispatchTimer to call
>   FrameworkDispatcher.Update in order to
>   simulate the Game loop for the XNA
>   Framework's internals. Finally, it
>   shows how to load a wave audio file
>   into a Stream that can be played by
>   the SoundEffect classes.